# Ajax request no response using codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

can anybody help me with this simple code,i have a button in which when a user submit it will load a javascript that will invoke ajax request to just update one field in my table so i passed a contoller that perform this method to my ajax request but nothing happens.here is my view

```
 <!--body part--->
  echo "<button class='btn btn-info dropdown-toggle notify-btn' data-toggle='dropdown' 'href='#' value=".$count." onclick='notify(".$count.")'>".$count."</button>"; 

 <!--Here is my javascript--->

 function notify(count){
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
           url:<?php echo base_url("notifications/set")?>,

        success:function(response){
            alert("Success");
        }
     });

            }

<!--Here is my Controller--->

     class Notifications extends CI_Controller{
     public function __construct()
     {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('notification_model');
     }

      public function index(){ 
         $this->set();
          }

        public function set(){
              $this->notification_model->set_notifications();
         }

<!--Here is my Model--->

 <?php class Notification_model extends CI_Model { 
            function set_notifications(){
                $this->db->where('notification_status','active');
                $this->db->set('notification_status',"inactive",FALSE);
                $this->db->update('messages');
            }
        }

?>
```

Comment: Please post your error messages that you are receiving in the js console

Comment: when i click nothng hapens,but i have solved this using the cjax codeigniter library,but stil wuld luv to knw hw to solve ths without any library.

Answer (score 0):

Just from having a quick look, it's possible that your AJAX request is failing as your URL isn't wrapped in single quotes. Try the following (notice the single quotes around the URL):

```
function notify(count){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url("notifications/set"); ?>',

        success:function(response){
            alert("Success");
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: when i click nothng hapens stil,but i have solved this using the cjax codeigniter library,but stil wuld luv to knw hw to solve ths without any library.thnks a lot for helping me out tho :-)